# How to pass variables in read while calling other feature files in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have a requirement like this -

1. feature1 calls the featurebase file.
2. In featurebase file, I am reading a json.
3. I want to configure the file reading via featurefile1.

I have my scripts like this.

FeatureBase -

```
Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * def requestBody = read('#(file)')
```

Feature1 -

```
Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * def callFeature = call read('FeatureBase.feature') { file: 'json1.json'}
```

This code doesn't work and gives me file not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'#(foo)'` trick applies only to JSON. Please read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Please change your code to:

```
* def requestBody = read(file)
```

Yes it is that simple, just like plain JavaScript.

Comment: thanks, @Peter that solved my problem.